# Choose of a lot of cases instead of c >= '0' && c <= '9' to 0-9 numbers checking

Tags: c, if-statement, switch-statement

The following code is part of an intepreter that I'm reading. I'm trying to figure why exactly use this instead of simple `c >= '0' && c <= '9'`?

```
switch(ch) {
  //...
  case '0': case '1': case '2': 
  case '3': case '4': case '5':
  case '6': case '7': case '8':
  case '9': 
  //etc
  break;
  //more cases
}
```

I'm very curios too why choose use a switch for that. How it is a code of a interpreter,I believe that the author have a background C know. Is this fastest than `c >= '0' && c <= '9'` condition or is this some way to leave the compiler make some optmization? it's compiled by using gcc

Comment: Can't answer this without seeing what the "more cases" are.  It might, for instance, be that the switch covers the *entire* set of characters that are meaningful to this language, and it is actually making an N-way choice with one jump table -- that's the sort of thing `switch` is really good at.  Or it might be that someone didn't know they could safely do `c >= '0' && c <= '9'`.  Or yet a third thing.  There's no way to tell from what you've given us.

Comment: It's fairly common practice in tokenisers to use `switch` - partly a holdover from days when `switch` always used a jump-table for speed. Even now, `switch` may not use a jump-table, but only because there's a better option (hard-coded binary search, for instance). It's harder for a compiler to see that an if/elseif/else conditional could be implemented the same way because the conditions are more flexible and could even have side-effects, though compilers get smarter all the time of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not use a condition in a switch `case`. If you want to use `c >= '0' && c <= '9'`, then you have to use an `if` statement, then it possibly makes checking other cases difficult, for example:

```
if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
  // ...
} else if (c == 'a') {
  // ...
} else if (c == 'b') {
  // ...
} else if (c == 'c') {
  // ...
} // more cases
```

will probably not be better than

```
switch(ch) {
  //...
  case '0': case '1': case '2': 
  case '3': case '4': case '5':
  case '6': case '7': case '8':
  case '9': 
  //etc
  break;
  case 'a': //...
  case 'b': //...
  case 'c': //...
  //etc
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Specifically for digits *only*, this is guaranteed to produce the same results as the equivalent `if`.

However, depending on the "more cases" part the code may be easier to read when written using `switch`. For example, if "more cases" wants to catch all lowercase letters it would be *theoretically* wrong to write the test like this:

```
if (c >= 'a' || c <= 'z')
```

so you would have to write it like this:

```
if (c == 'a' || c == 'b' || ...)
```

In this case, it's much easier to use `switch` than `if`/`elseif`.

Comment: Expanding on that "theoretically wrong" - one reason may be [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Binary_Coded_Decimal_Interchange_Code), a more common reason that (depending on language and character set) there may be more lowercase letters to consider. That said, you have to know what those letters are whether you use `if` or `switch` - it's more a case for using `islower` and family.

Answer (score 2):

maybe

```
if(isdigit(ch)){
    //etc
} else {
    //more cases
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Zack mentioned, it depends a great deal on what the "more cases" are.  Many compilers will generate an optimized combination of conditional instructions and jump tables when there are a lot of cases in the switch.  It's not necessarily just a matter of readability.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `GCC` or `Clang` you can also write:

```
switch(ch) {
  //...
  case '0' ... '9': 
  //stuff
  break;
  //more cases
}
```